# Shutdown service after the service has done its job

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am creating a service which watch for a file and as soon as file is available it loads it to db. Once this job is done I want to shutdown the app gracefully.

But when I use context.close it throws exception (though the app shuts down) but I want to shut it down without causing any exception.

```
@profile("non-test")
class Manager implements ApplicationContextAware{

@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    //watch for file and as soon as file  is available invokde trigger()
}

public void trigger()
{
    //load to db
    shutodown()
}

public void shutdown()
{
    SpringApplication.exit(context);
}
}
```

when i call shutdown it throws below exception.
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext has already been closed

I want the app to shutdown gracefully without any exception.

Comment: First of all, let's correct terminology. You are talking about batch job, not service.

Comment: Sorry, correct its a batch job which does its job and should come down

Comment: Can you post list of Spring dependencies your application has?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is most probably presence of Spring dependency that makes your app long lived. Such dependency is for example spring-boot-starter-web. This starter includes Servlet container as dependency ans Spring will by default be running forever.

If non of such dependencies is on classpath, your Spring Boot app would shut down automatically (without any special effort to kill it). I would suggest to take a look at some of [Spring guides for batch job](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/).